Azure Communication Service - "The app is trying to access a service '1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a" error., then known solution does not work

I am Owner in the subscription
I am Cloud Application Administrator in the Entra ID tenant
I am doing all steps described below (and also in the tutorial) a fresh new private browser window

I am trying to follow to follow: Set up and manage access tokens for Teams users In Step 5, I running into the issue, exactly what the author foreseen, and the author also described the the solution for the issue in case it happens:
Issue what the author foreseen and described in Step 5:

If you run into the issue "The app is trying to access a service '1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a'(Azure Communication Services) that your organization '{GUID}' lacks a service principal for....

Solution what the author described in Step 5 in the case if the issue above occurs: (note the guid is fixed, means it belongs to Azure Communication Services, so not mine, or custom)
PS> Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "my tenant guid" -Scopes Application.ReadWrite.All
PS> New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId "1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a"

I am executing this proposed solution in my Azure Cloud Shell. The graph autentication is success, but New-MgServicePrincipal gives 403 (Forbidden):

New-MgServicePrincipal_CreateExpanded: Insufficient privileges to
complete the operation.
Status: 403 (Forbidden) ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied Date:
2024-05-03T07:32:18
Headers: Cache-Control                 : no-cache Vary
: Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : 7----8
client-request-id             : b---4
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North
Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"009","RoleInstance":"D*3"}}
x-ms-resource-unit            : 1 Date                          : Fri,
03 May 2024 07:32:17 GM

Either the 403 Forbidden error message is misleading and something else is wrong, or in case I really has no sufficient privileges, then what it is?
Any idea, from this point it is really hopeless to googling (btw I tried it, but the max I can find, is the solution what the author was described)

For single-tenant app if you are the owner of the backing application, you must have the Application Developer role.

Did you grant eligible or active role assignments for Cloud Application Administrator  role?

@Rukmini, unfortunately I do not understand neither your recommendations, I am *in the Cloud Application Administrator role, which is a built in role. Also, what do you mean on "assigning the role as active"?

Assign role Cloud Application Administrator like this

@user2250152, I am in Owner role in the subscription... what do you mean on Application Developer role

@Rukmini I have no right to make role assignments in the Entra ID tenant (the subscription is where I am in the owner role. I just see that my user is in the "Cloud Application Administrator" role. Is there a way I can see my role membership is active or eligible?

@g.pickardou Go to Users -> Select User -> Assigned roles

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Rukimi, many thx it is working now after I got the Global Administrator role. @
user2250152, if I will have time with the admin, we intend to try if the Application Developer role is enough or not.

@g.pickardou did  you assign Global admin role to the user to perform the action?

Yes, after that New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId "1fd5118e-2576-4263-8130-9503064c837a" ran successful, and after that I the consent url did not throw the error, so the consent could be given successfully

I assigned owner role to the user like below:

Assigned Cloud Application Administrator role as Eligible:

Now when I tried to create the Service Principal, I got the same error as below:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Application.ReadWrite.All
New-MgServicePrincipal -AppId "AppID"


Hence to resolve the error, I assigned an Active Cloud Application Administrator role to the user:


Now I am able to create the Service Principal successfully:

Assign Global Administrator role to make the role changes or If still the issue persists, assign Application Developer role to the user as suggested by @user2250152
And only Application Administrator or Cloud Application Administrator or Application Developer role is required to create Service principal.
